# C++23 std::views::zip errors when given a view of references to abstract base class

Tags: c++, abstract-class, std-pair, std-ranges, c++23

Given this program, compiled with `g++-13 -std=c++2b test.cpp`:

...where that is...

```
g++-13 (Debian 13-20230106-1) 13.0.0 20230106 (experimental) [master r13-5040-g53add162511]
```

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <ranges>

auto
main() -> int
{
    struct B    { virtual void foo() = 0; };
    struct D: B { virtual void foo() {}   };

    auto ds = std::array<D, 10>{};
    auto to_b = [](D const& d) -> B const& { return d; };
    auto bs = ds | std::views::transform(to_b);

    for (auto& b: bs) {} // OK

    auto zip = std::views::zip(ds, bs);

    for (auto&& pair: zip) {} // error

    return 0;
}
```

Trying to loop over a `std::views::zip` in which one of the zipped ranges should be a reference to an abstract base class... just doesn't work. The errors are these:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/13/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from /usr/include/c++/13/array:43,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/13/bits/stl_pair.h: In instantiation of ‘struct std::pair<main()::D, main()::B>’:
/usr/include/c++/13/type_traits:3744:12:   recursively required by substitution of ‘template<class _Tp1, class _Tp2> struct std::__common_reference_impl<_Tp1&&, _Tp2&, 1, std::void_t<typename std::__common_ref_impl<_Tp1&&, _Tp2&, void>::type> > [with _Tp1 = std::pair<main()::D&, const main()::B&>; _Tp2 = std::pair<main()::D, main()::B>]’
/usr/include/c++/13/type_traits:3744:12:   required from ‘struct std::common_reference<std::pair<main()::D&, const main()::B&>&&, std::pair<main()::D, main()::B>&>’
/usr/include/c++/13/type_traits:3724:11:   required by substitution of ‘template<class ... _Tp> using std::common_reference_t = typename std::common_reference::type [with _Tp = {std::pair<main()::D&, const main()::B&>&&, std::pair<main()::D, main()::B>&}]’
/usr/include/c++/13/bits/iterator_concepts.h:324:13:   required by substitution of ‘template<class _Iterator>  requires (__iter_without_nested_types<_Iterator>) && (__cpp17_input_iterator<_Iterator>) struct std::__iterator_traits<_Iter, void> [with _Iterator = std::ranges::zip_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::array<main()::D, 10> >, std::ranges::transform_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::array<main()::D, 10> >, main()::<lambda(const main()::D&)> > >::_Iterator<false>]’
/usr/include/c++/13/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:177:12:   required from ‘struct std::iterator_traits<std::ranges::zip_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::array<main()::D, 10> >, std::ranges::transform_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::array<main()::D, 10> >, main()::<lambda(const main()::D&)> > >::_Iterator<false> >’
/usr/include/c++/13/bits/iterator_concepts.h:211:4:   required by substitution of ‘template<class _Iter, class _Tp>  requires  __primary_traits_iter<_Iter> struct std::__detail::__iter_traits_impl<_Iter, _Tp> [with _Iter = std::ranges::zip_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::array<main()::D, 10> >, std::ranges::transform_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::array<main()::D, 10> >, main()::<lambda(const main()::D&)> > >::_Iterator<false>; _Tp = std::incrementable_traits<std::ranges::zip_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::array<main()::D, 10> >, std::ranges::transform_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::array<main()::D, 10> >, main()::<lambda(const main()::D&)> > >::_Iterator<false> >]’
/usr/include/c++/13/bits/iterator_concepts.h:224:13:   required by substitution of ‘template<class _Iter, class _Tp> using std::__detail::__iter_traits = typename std::__detail::__iter_traits_impl::type [with _Iter = std::ranges::zip_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::array<main()::D, 10> >, std::ranges::transform_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::array<main()::D, 10> >, main()::<lambda(const main()::D&)> > >::_Iterator<false>; _Tp = std::incrementable_traits<std::ranges::zip_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::array<main()::D, 10> >, std::ranges::transform_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::array<main()::D, 10> >, main()::<lambda(const main()::D&)> > >::_Iterator<false> >]’
/usr/include/c++/13/bits/iterator_concepts.h:227:13:   required by substitution of ‘template<class _Tp> using std::__detail::__iter_diff_t = typename std::__detail::__iter_traits_impl<_Tp, std::incrementable_traits<_Iter> >::type::difference_type [with _Tp = std::ranges::zip_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::array<main()::D, 10> >, std::ranges::transform_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::array<main()::D, 10> >, main()::<lambda(const main()::D&)> > >::_Iterator<false>]’
/usr/include/c++/13/bits/iterator_concepts.h:232:11:   required by substitution of ‘template<class _Tp> using std::iter_difference_t = std::__detail::__iter_diff_t<typename std::remove_cvref<_Tp>::type> [with _Tp = std::ranges::zip_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::array<main()::D, 10> >, std::ranges::transform_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::array<main()::D, 10> >, main()::<lambda(const main()::D&)> > >::_Iterator<false>]’
/usr/include/c++/13/ranges:4436:26:   required from ‘constexpr auto std::ranges::zip_view<_Vs>::end() requires !((__simple_view<_Vs> && ...)) [with _Vs = {std::ranges::ref_view<std::array<main()::D, 10> >, std::ranges::transform_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::array<main()::D, 10> >, main()::<lambda(const main()::D&)> >}]’
test.cpp:18:20:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/13/bits/stl_pair.h:194:11: error: cannot declare field ‘std::pair<main()::D, main()::B>::second’ to be of abstract type ‘main()::B’
  194 |       _T2 second;                ///< The second member
      |           ^~~~~~
test.cpp:7:16: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘main()::B’:
    7 |         struct B    { virtual void foo() = 0; };
      |                ^
test.cpp:7:36: note:     ‘virtual void main()::B::foo()’
    7 |         struct B    { virtual void foo() = 0; };
```

Is this correct? I don't think I'm asking for a `std::pair<D, B>`; I think I'm asking for a `std::pair<D&, B&>`. I don't see where I am or should be causing an abstract `B` to be constructed. I would totally understand the error if I *was*... but *am I*...?

I've read the 2 Standard papers about `std::views::zip` and various discussion of issues around `reference`s and `value_type`, but I don't see anything to explain this.

So, either I've missed some crucial detail in the Standard papers and/or diagnostics (more likely?)... or perhaps there's a gremlin in `libstdc++` (less likely?) that tries to instantiate `pair<D, B>` when not needed - and I'd appreciate input from the better-versed anyway :)

Comment: C++23 hasn't even been published. Why do you think that these experimental implementations of an unfinished standard are free of bugs?

Comment: @NicolBolas Why do you think I think that? The point of the question is to determine if the intent of the Standard is to allow what I was trying to do or not, i.e. if it erroring is _not_ a bug. What an unhelpful comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterators don't just have `reference` (unfortunately named, since not always a language reference), they also have a `value_type`. In Ranges, a lot of this model is more formalized. The core concept of C++20 input iterators is [`indirectly_readable`](https://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.concept.readable), of which the key parts are basically:

- an iterator has a `value_type`
- an iterator has a `reference`, which is the type you get by doing `*ci`  on a `const I` (note the `const`. Also note that `*i` and `*ci` have to be the same type)
- there is a common reference between `reference&&` and `value_type&` (note the `&`)

There are other requirements which you can see, but those are the most relevant ones here. Typically (tho not always), `value_type` is just `remove_cvref_t<reference>`. One case where this isn't the case is `zip_view<Rs...>`, where `reference` is `tuple<range_reference_t<Rs>...>` and `value_type` is `tuple<range_value_t<Rs>...>`.

Now, with the `transform` example, you have `reference` is `B&` and `value_type` is `B`. This is fine, since the common reference requirement would use `B&` (not `B`), and you're not doing anything else that tries to construct a `B` (e.g. calling `ranges::min` or something).

But with the `zip` example, let's say actually we were just doing `zip(bs)`. Here, `reference` is going to be `tuple<B&>`, but what is `value_type`? Well, it kind of has to be `tuple<B>`, but you can't make a `tuple<B>`, so that's ill-formed (in the actual OP it's a `std::pair`, but there was a recent change to always use `std::tuple`, the difference doesn't matter here).

---

So, okay, what can we actually do? There isn't actually another `value_type` we can produce. Reusing `tuple<B&>` is a bad idea, that would break any algorithm you use that actually wants to have a *value* type.

The only alternative is... not having a `value_type` at all here. There are quite a few algorithms that don't use `value_type` (the simplest of which is just the `for` loop you're trying to do), and it admittedly kind of sucks to not be able to support those algorithms due to a requirement that... you're not using. But that's the design as it exists right now and it would, I think, be difficult to change.

---

So the solution really is to just try to avoid ranges of `Abstract&`. `Abstract*` would work fine, since there you'd end up with a `value_type` of `Abstract*` also. Or `reference_wrapper<Abstract>`, which would at least make it clear that you don't have null pointers.

Comment: Thanks. So, this is expected, and not an issue in the library? And indeed, I realised I can use `Abstract*` or `reference_wrapper<Abstract>` and in fact ended up using the latter, another benefit of which is implicit conversion _back_ to `Abstract&` in suitable contexts (and `.get()` for the rest).

Comment: Also, thanks for all your (and others') work on getting so many invaluable ranges, views, and other things into C++20/23/onwards. I'll soon not know how to code without them :-)

Comment: At the risk of asking a silly question... where is `zip_view[::iterator]::reference` specified? AFAICS, both P2321R2 and cppreference only describe `iterator::value_type`. I know that `iter_reference_t = decltype(*std::declval<T&>());`, but obviously since `zip[::iterator]` wraps its base ranges' types in a `tuple`, doesn't that need special handling? But I didn't yet find anywhere that describes how `::reference` is worked out. So does it follow naturally from some other rule that I've currently overlooked? **edit**: ah, `iterator::operator*()` is defined via `/* tuple-transform */`, so that?

Comment: @underscore_d `reference` isn't an alias, it's _just_ the type that `op*()` returns. So yeah, it's the result of that `tuple_transform` which is `tuple<range_reference_t<Rs>...>`